# Can I use ArcServe Alert without Microsoft Exchange Server?

Tags: email, backup

I want to get my ArcServe job to generate emails for me because lately I have not been in the office to babysit the backup jobs. Unfortunately I do not have exchange in house and all the settings in the Alert SMTP configuration deals with an Exchange mailbox.

My support subscription literally just ran out with CA so I was hoping someone here can save me the effort by letting me know if it flat out wont work or if they've figured it out.

I run ArcServe r15 build 6222.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. See the Support Page of CA: http://supportconnect.ca.com/sc/redir.jsp?reqPage=search&searchID=TEC379982

To cite the relevant:

> SMTP
>
> Allows sending of e-mail messages to Exchange 2003 and other e-mail
>   systems which use SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol).
>
> This requires an SMTP service to be available on the machine sending
>   the alert.

**Edit**
The above was from an older version. But the new one has a [manual](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/c013051e.pdf) and the same information is on page 689ff.

Comment: I configured my server as a smtp relay. And I configured Arcserve with the address of localhost. Everything goes from Alert into badmail. This is a recurring problem with my relay. It wont deliver mail. Unfortunately it seems that they do not let you specify a smtp port anywhere in Alert and mine is non-standard. I let WSUS directly email to my external smtp. Was hoping Arcserve would let me do the same until I figure out why the relay does not work. Thank you mailq.

Comment: No no no. As I understand it you can only give an email address. So the standard way is that a client (Arcserve in this case) determines the MX record of that address and delivers to port 25 of it. If there is no MX then the same happens for the A record. But an SMTP client (in this case in the role of a MTA) will always deliver on port 25 as of RFC 5321. This procedure is called direct-to-MX. What would be a better (but not implemented) solution is to configure a relay server/port in Arcserve.

Answer (score -1):

You might try something like smtpsend or blat

Comment: Why? It is even included in Arcserve!

Comment: Poster indicated he didn't have Exchange, so what would he be relaying off of?  Maybe Arcsoft comes with it's own smtp.

Comment: Yes Arcserve has a built-in SMTP client. This is enough to contact any SMTP server. And your suggestions are only SMTP clients that can be triggered from Arcserve in which way?